# STM32F302R8 ADC injected configuration weirdness

Tags: adc

I'm seeing strange behavior trying to write to the ADC1_JSQR register. This register controls the channel sequence and the trigger source of injected conversions. After enabling the ADC (ADEN=1), a write to bits 7:0 (JEXTEN, JEXTSEL & JL) locks out further writes to ADC1_JSQR so that subsequent writes are ignored. Writes from both C and gdb seem to exhibit the same behavior.

Paragraph 15.3.10 "Constraints when writing the ADC control bits" in RM0365 makes me wonder if writing to the ADC registers in the wrong order. Writing to the ADC1_JSQx[4:0] fields before bits 7:0 seems to work.

I have two Nucleo-F302R8 boards and both work the same.

Is this a hardware bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
static void setup_adc(uint32_t adc)
{                                                                                           
    uint8_t regular_sequence[] = { 6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 16, 6, 18 };
    uint8_t injected_sequence[] = { 7, 7, 7, 7 };
    
    adc_power_off(adc);
    adc_enable_temperature_sensor();                            // CCR
    adc_set_clk_prescale(adc, ADC_CCR_CKMODE_DIV2);             // CCR
    adc_set_single_conversion_mode(adc);                        // CFGR1(CONT) = ~CONT
    
    adc_calibrate(adc);                                         // CR(ADCAL) = 1
    adc_power_on(adc);                                          // CR(ADEN) = 1

    adc_set_resolution(adc, ADC_CFGR1_RES_12_BIT);              // CFGR1
    adc_set_sample_time_on_all_channels(adc, ADC_SMPR_SMP_19DOT5CYC ); // SMPR1 & SMPR2
    adc_enable_dma_circular_mode(adc);                          // CFGR1(DMACFG) = 1
    adc_set_right_aligned(adc);                                 // CFGR1(ALIGN) = 0
    adc_enable_dma(adc);                                        // CFGR1(DMAEN) = 1
        
    adc_enable_external_trigger_regular(adc,                    // CFGR1(EXTSEL,EXTEN)
        ADC_CFGR1_EXTSEL_VAL(13), 1<<10 );                      // TIM6; rising edge
    adc_set_regular_sequence(adc, ADC_CHAN, regular_sequence);  // SQRx
        
    adc_set_injected_sequence(adc, 4, injected_sequence);       // JSQR(JL) = 4
    adc_enable_external_trigger_injected(adc,                   // JSQR(JEXTSEL,JEXTEN)
        ADC_JSQR_JEXTSEL_EVENT_1,                               // TIM1_OC4REF event
        ADC_JSQR_JEXTEN_FALLING_EDGE );     
}
```